# Android Transition between Activities from non-Activity Class

Tags: java, android, transition

I'm using an activity context from a non-activity class.
I don't want any transition between Activities, but sometimes there is no transition and sometimes there is.

Here is my code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.context, Lose.class);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
((Activity)context).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

Does anyone understands what part of my code causes this inconsistent behaviour?

Comment: Switch directly the screens without any animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your Intent:

```
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
```